# Change name to number with prefix

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem. I would like to change the names into numbers, so that instead of the name there is a number. In addition, I would like the number to be preceded by a name, e.g. `Max Power` becomes `Name 0`.

When I use cat codes and then append a string, I get the following error

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U5'), dtype('int8')) -> None
```

How can I change the name to a number and put the name in front of it?

Dataframe

```py
             name
0       Max Power
1  Erik Fullpower
2       Sofia Cat
```

Code

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'name': ['Max Power', 'Erik Fullpower', 'Sofia Cat']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


name = df['name'].astype('category').cat.codes
name = "Name " + name
```

What I want

```py
             name
0       Name 0
1       Name 1
2       Name 2
```

Erorr

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-68feb913163d> in <module>
      1 name = df['name'].astype('category').cat.codes
----> 2 name = "Name " + name

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/roperator.py in radd(left, right)
      7 
      8 def radd(left, right):
----> 9     return right + left
     10 
     11 

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U5'), dtype('int8')) -> None
```

Comment: Well the `codes` are integer type, and to concat with a string, you need to change to string type. so `name = "Name " + df['name'].astype('category').cat.codes.astype(str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this>? or just name ?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'name': ['Max Power', 'Erik Fullpower', 'Sofia Cat']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['name'] = df.assign(index=df.index.astype(str)).agg(' '.join, 1)
print(df)
```

output#

```
               name
0       Max Power 0
1  Erik Fullpower 1
2       Sofia Cat 2
```

or

More simpler

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'name': ['Max Power', 'Erik Fullpower', 'Sofia Cat']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
 

df['name'] =  df['name'] +' '+ df.index.astype(str)

print(df)
```

#output

```
               name
0       Max Power 0
1  Erik Fullpower 1
2       Sofia Cat 2
```

I'm so confused so Just adding another possible answer

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'name': ['Max Power', 'Erik Fullpower', 'Sofia Cat']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['name_'] = 'name'

df['name_'] =  df['name_'] +' '+ df.index.astype(str)

print(df)
```

output#

```
             name   name_
0       Max Power  name 0
1  Erik Fullpower  name 1
2       Sofia Cat  name 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['name2'] = 'Name ' + (df['name'].astype('category').cat.codes).astype(str)
df
```

```
    name            name2
0   Max Power       Name 1
1   Erik Fullpower  Name 0
2   Sofia Cat       Name 2
```

Comment: Why numbers are like 1,0,2?...name 1, name 0 , name 2...It should be name 0, name 1, name 2 right?